# chrome.management.getAll - Problems to store values (wait time)

Tags: asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I got a problem that I know is because of a asynchronous method.
I need to store all my chrome extensions in a array.
Code with problem:

```
1  var ArrayExtensions = new Array ();<br>
2  chrome.management.getAll(function (info) {<br>
3  for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {<br>
4  if (info[i].type== "extension" ){<br>
5  ArrayExtensions.push(info[i].name);}}   });<br>
6  for (var i = 0; i < ArrayExtensions.length; i++) {<br>
7  alert(ArrayExtensions[i]);<br>
8  }
```

With this code I don't get any alert window.

But when I add `alert(ArrayExtensions.length);` between line 5 and 6 and in line 9 I got a alert with number 0, the names of my extensions (code working) and the last window show the correct number of extensions.

Clearly I need to wait some time to the method store the values in the array, but how can I solve this problem in a better way ?

Comment: Why not move lines 6-8 into the callback?

Comment: I was thinking that the listener chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener can be fired any time, so I wanted to wait until the chrome.management.getAll was done this will be the better solution ?

    if(ArrayExtensions.length != 0) {chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener}